# How can I access variables that are concealed within an Object from global?

Tags: javascript

I read over and over that global variables and functions are bad and they must be avoided at all cost. But I've been unable to achieve this. I'm sure this question has been asked many times and I've read them on SO, but I still don't fully understand.

I have an object that has several methods that need to be called on specific events (e.g. button click). I can conceal everything in an anonymous function, but once I do that, I can no longer call the methods within the object from outside. The only way to avoid this is to expose an object to the global space so that it can call a method within the object.

Hers is what I mean by that.

JavaScript

```
(function () { // using anonymous function to conceal variables/functions
    function Ninja (name) {
        this.name = name;

        this.hide = function () {
            alert("Find me if you can!");
        };

        this.kill = function (target) {
            alert(name + " killed " + target + ".");
        };
    }

    this.myNinja = new Ninja (""); // ... but I need to expose the object to global space
})();
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="myNinja.hide()">Click Me</button>
```

How can I prevent things from going global, but still being able to call methods defined the concealed Object? Is this even possible?

Comment: It's not "possible", but you can make a single, big object that your whole application uses. So of course, that would be declared globally. Then, you'd set a property on that object (like `myNinja`), and access the big object instead of putting it in `window`. So like `var AppObject = {};` (in the global scope), then later: `AppObject.myNinja = new Ninja("");` instead in your code above

Comment: @lan I see. But the reason why I worry about exposing an object to the global space is that if I have an object sitting in the global space, this means viewers of my web site can get access to the object in the browser console. They can easily look at my JavaScript codes and execute various functions. I believe this threatens the security of my web site. For example, if I have a function called removePassword() that removes a password to a protected page, attacker can just call the function using the object in the global space.

Comment: I completely understand. But that's what you have to understand with Javascript. That will always be possible. If you want another part of your website to be able to call something (especially in an inline event handler), there's definitely no way to hide it fully (you can try to confuse the people attempting to do what you're talking about though). It's different if all the code you want to access is within a closure like you have. For example, you could bind the event inside that closure and access that, still keeping it private elsewhere.

Comment: Look into using a pattern like the revealing module pattern to have private variables/functions and privileged variables function. It would look something like this.

`var exposedObj = (function() {
    var public = "I'm a public var",
        private = "I'm private",

        showPrivateVar: function() {
            console.log("Here is the private var" + private);
        };

    return {
        public: public,
        showPrivateVar: showPrivateVar
    };
})();`

In this example you cannot directly access the private variable. Same work for making a private function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after here; what you have should already work. Hiding would be better if you didn't use inline js.

Comment: Thank you all. So if I bind event handlers within the closure as opposed to attaching within HTML like I did, I can still conceal everything. This seems like the way to go. And thanks @JulianFeliciano for the nice example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent globalizing your objects, you should define your event listeners inside the closure as well:

```
(function () { // using anonymous function to conceal variables/functions
    // Ninja declaration
    var ninja = new Ninja('');

    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]
        .addEventListener('click', function() {
            ninja.hide();
        }, false);
})();
```

The exact method of attaching event handler varies between browsers, this should work on most modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`this.myNinja = new Ninja ("");`

to

`window.myNinja = new Ninja ("");`

Comment: Unless in strict mode both are the same, also I think OP want to have global access to a non-global variable

Comment: `this` is bound to the global object for function invocation expressions.